# How To Fetch Random Row From MySQL Database Table Without Numeric ID?

Tags: mysql, database, perl, random

I have a sharded MySQL database table spread across a number of servers, and want to have a function to fetch a random record.

The way I see it, the best way to do this is:

1. Choose a random shard in the (Perl) application layer.
2. Choose a random row from the table on that shard.

This question will focus on part 2 of the solution.

My table does not have a numeric ID, we decided to use GUIDs in order to avoid the overhead of having to maintain a ticketing service. We combine our GUID with a shard identifier in order to ensure they are unique.

Table is something like this:

```
guid                                        name      details
003-b0470602-a64b-11da-8632-93ebf1c0e05a    Aura      Some details
```

The best answer I've come up with so far was suggested by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack), which is to:

1. Count the number of records in the database.
2. Get a random number between 1 and the result from step 1.
3. `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT {result from step 2}`
4. Take the last result from this (potentially very large) result set.

I'm worried that the processing involved in this could be quite large (though certainly better than `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, and wondering if anyone has any better solutions which work with a non numeric identifier.

Comment: +1. Question is now 20% cooler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIMIT 1 OFFSET N` (where N is from 0 to number of records-1) would be better, less records transferred from DB server, and no need to generate random data for the sort.

Additionally, some RMDBs might perform that offset very efficiently - but I don't know if MySQL will on your table definition, you should test the performance.

Comment: Wow, I didn't actually know the `OFFSET` keyword existed. Thanks.